# Remove a Dynamic Suffix Pattern from String in Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I have data in the format below:

```
2.7G58%/usr
8%/oravl02
49%/oravl01
98%/osszoneusr/osszone/user
```

and I need to remove everything from beginning of the line to the percentage so that the output of above sample data would be:

```
/usr
/oravl02
/oravl01
/osszoneusr/osszone/user
```

I am specifically looking for linux in-built string striping or sed as in solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '%' '{print $2}' file
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^.*%//' file
```

Using `cut`:

```
cut -d% -f2 file
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` variation.

```
awk -F% '$0=$NF' file
/usr
/oravl02
/oravl01
/osszoneusr/osszone/user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try  in below ways

cut: the delimiter must be a single character

bcsmc2rtese001 [~/Shell_p]$ cut -d '%' -f2 text1.txt  
/usr  
/oravl02   
/oravl01  


bcsmc2rtese001 [~/Shell_p]$ awk -F "%" '{print $2}' text1.txt  
/usr  
/oravl02  
/oravl01  
/osszoneusr/osszone/user
```